# Solidity - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contract' of undefined"

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am somewhat new to the Mix IDE and ethereum (solidity specifically) and I have a naive question. How does the javascript code in my web page get "tied" to the contract code? I wrote a simple web page that takes in a value, but the javascript can't seem to pass the value to the actual contract. The exact error line is:

```
var result = contracts["MyFirstContract"].contract.reportUser("foo");
```

The exact error Mix is giving me is:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contract' of undefined."

So it apparently sees *contracts["MyFirstContract"]* as nil

However, the MyFirstContract.sol file exists! How does the javascript know what contract file I am talking about? It doesn't seem to appear in the documentation, although I may be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. It seems that the javascript code does not access the .col files directly. It gets contract code directly from the blockchain, not the actual .col file. So you have to compile and uploaded the contract to the blockchain before your javascript can see it.

You have to add the transaction to the test blockchain. In the Mix IDE, you have to press "Add Transaction" button available in the "Right view" pane (F7 pulls up the "Right View" pane). Once the dialogue box opens up, press the "Create Contract" radio button and choose the contract that you just created from the pulldown menu. Press OK, and Mix creates a transaction with your contract code in it. Then try out your javascript, it should work.